# mysql join a table to itself from a bridging table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that references each other via id. I want to connect a given name in the first table, to a relation with one or many persons using a second table. See example

### Person

| id | name | Adress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jonas | Sturmwind Street 12 5431 |
| 2 | Thomas | New Banksy Home 14 5432 |
| 3 | Therese | Redcarpet Willow 1 6623 |
| 4 | Nicko | Redcarpet Willow 1 6623 |
| 5 | Sandra | Mcmurdo Station |

### Related

| related_from_id | related_to_id | Relation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | "Sibling" |
| 1 | 5 | "Sibling" |
| 3 | 4 | "Parent" |

Given a name, how can I make a mysql query that gives me any potential siblings name and adress.

For instance I query with param "Jonas" and expect the result set to be

### Relation

| Name | Related to | Adress |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jonas | "Thomas" | "New Banksy Home 14 5432" |
|  | "Sandra" | "Mcmurdo Station" |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have your result

```
SELECT 
  p.name AS NAME,
  p1.name AS relatedTo,
  p1.Address 
FROM
  Person p,
  Related r,
  Person p1 
WHERE r.related_from_id = p.id 
  AND r.related_to_id = p1.id 
  AND p.name = 'Jonas' ;
```

However, if the relationship is in any direction, @The Impater's answer has you covered.

Comment: Thank you. I had no idea you could rename/alias the tables in the from clause.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you want to walk the `related` table in any direction (left-right or right-left).

You can do:

```
select p.name, o.name as related_to, o.address
from person p
join related r on p.id in (r.related_from_id, r.related_to_id)
join person o on r.related_from_id = p.id and o.id = related_to_id
              or r.related_to_id = p.id and o.id = related_from_id
where p.name = 'Jonas'
```